# Class file doesn't seem to do fleqn option for beamer properly

Tags: beamer, amsmath

I'm trying to do a set of beamer slides with the equations flush left. A minimal example is below. The fleqn option doesn't seem to have any effect. When I combine the class file and tex file into a single file, using `\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}`, the equation is flush left, as expected. Presumably I'm making a mistake in my class file, but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{talk}

\LoadClass[fleqn]{beamer}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

Tex file:

```
\documentclass{talk}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Foo}
  When in the course
  \begin{equation*}
  x=y
  \end{equation*}
  of human events\ldots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That doesn't work. I get this error: `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package amsmath.` As far as I can tell, beamer wants you to supply the fleqn option to it, which it then wants to pass on to amsmath. And that is indeed what works when I do this as a single file rather than with a separate class file.

Comment: yes it would work if you loaded it before beamer, or you can stop beamer loading amsmath first as egreg showed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option you pass to `beamer` is not global, so it's not inherited by `amsmath`, which is loaded by `beamer` with no option. So you can't load it later.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{talk}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\LoadClass{beamer}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

[image]

Alternatively

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{talk}

\LoadClass[noamsthm]{beamer}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```